# SQL Foreign Key Relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I am trying to create a contact database of contacts at various companies.   Contact persons and businesses are going to be stored in two separate tables in the database. I want each contact to  be connected to a specific company. Am I supposed to use Foreign Key for all columns in the entire table or how is it made?

Contact table has following attributes:

```
Firstname
Lastname
Email
Phone
```

And company table has:

```
Name
```

I do not want anymore columns!

Comment: You will need to have more columns if you want a relationship between the two tables.

Comment: You need to read about and understand data normalization in more detail. Of course you don't have all the data in both tables. That would defeat the point of relational data entirely. You would create a CompanyID in the contact table which would have a foreign key reference to CompanyID in the Companies table.

Comment: Then you're screwed. You cannot add that functionality without adding more columns.  If contacts can be in more than one company, first you need a Primary Key (PK) column in Contacts table (say ContactId).Then,best would be to add another table with just ContactId and CompanyName.(as a 2-column PK).  If contacts can only be in one company, you need to add CompanyName to Contacts table

Comment: @CharlesBretana you wouldn't need a CompanyContact type table unless a given contact could be attached to more than 1 company.

Comment: How should the FK look?

Comment: @Sean, gosh you have to be fast on this forum! I must have edited my comment to reflect that within 30 secs of posting it!

Comment: @CharlesBretana lol yeah i still had the page up. :)

Comment: @Malphai how could we know? You haven't shared your table structure. I would suggest it being just like what I stated in my original comment. You are going to have to add another column in each table here if you want any kind of chance at this. Again, I would strongly recommend you read about normalization and foreign keys. It sounds like you might not have a really solid handle on that concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.  To address your comments on how the FK should look, this is the table structure you should be looking for:

```
Create Table Contact
(
    Id          Int Identity(1,1) Not Null Primary Key Clustered,
    Firstname   Varchar (20),
    Lastname    Varchar (20),
    Email       Varchar (50),
    Phone       Varchar (15),
    CompanyId   Int Not Null
)

Create Table Company
(
    Id          Int Identity(1,1) Not Null Primary Key Clustered,
    Name        Varchar (100)
)

Alter Table Contact 
Add Constraint FK_Contact_Company 
Foreign Key (CompanyId) References Company (Id)
```

You need to add an `Identity` column to your tables to act as their `Primary Keys`.

Next, you need to add a `CompanyId` column to your `Contact` table to hold the relationship.

And finally, you need to create the actual `Foreign Key Constraint`.

*Your datatypes are surely different from what I've guessed at, but this is the concept you should be using for your Foreign Key relationships.*

Comment: So if I just simply copy your code and add it to the query, I will get the result I want?

Comment: If you copied the code I provided, it would create the two tables you mentioned in the question with the foreign key constraint added.  If you already have the tables made, running this script will fail.  You'll need to incorporate this into what you already have.

Comment: Yes I deleted the previous tables and executed this code. It is exactly as I described, thank you for your help!